# wordpress templating get the content of parent page

Tags: wordpress, templates

how do i get the_content for the parent page when templating in WP?

(pages-only structure)

preferably wo plugins or sql.

regards,
/t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php $page = get_page(); // gets current page ID
      $parentID = $page['post_parent']; // gets parent ID, if there is one
      if($parentID != '0') {
        $parentPage = get_page($parentID);
        $parentContent = $parentPage['post_content']; // gets raw content
        $parentContent = apply_filters('the_content', $parentContent); // filters content
      } ?>
```

That's one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`$parent = get_post($post->post_parent);`

then you can do

`$parentContent = $parent->post_content`

FYI, `get_page()` wraps `get_post()`